# Functional C# - using or returning Action's

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, higher-order-functions

Browsing the net for better fault handling in C#, I've com across the following to implementation strategies. The first one is natural to me, while the other implementation I'm not certain what its advantages are?

1)
 
`static void Fault(Action protectedBlock, Action faultHandler)
{ 
    try
    {
        protectedBlock();
    }
    catch
    {
        faultHandler();
        throw;
    }

}`

2)

```
static Action Fault(Action protectedBlock, Action faultHandler)
{
    return () =>
    {
        try
        {
            protectedBlock();
        }
        catch
        {
            faultHandler();
            throw;
        }
    };
}
```

Is 2) the preferred strategy when developing higher order functions in C#?

And, I am wondering, if one approach is more efficient than the other.

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's 'blog entries on Continuation Passing Style. For your example, he's done [a whole post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/22/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-two-handwaving-about-control-flow.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second case is like a Faultable Action Factory. Where you pass in a delegate of what you want to do, `protectedBlock`, and a delegate of what to do when an `Exception` occurs, `faultHandler`. The actions are returned wrapped in a try/catch structure as an aggregate `Action`. My problem with both these methods is no `Exception` is actually being caught so who ever is going to catch your throw has no information on which to act.

The difference in execution between the 2 is when they actually execute. The 1st will be executed when it's called. The 2nd will execute whenever the returned `Action` is called. I don't think the efficiency difference would be significant.

Comment: First, I'm not sure I understand your problem? To me the Fault() is just a way of cleaning up the resources, not a way to define a re-try strategy. Speaking of which, I've found that in business applications, 99% of the time, you can't do much else than log the incident and show the error to the user.

Comment: @Carlo V. Dango: The try/catch doesn't clean up resources. Maybe you are thinking of a Using statement, which is equivalent to a try/catch/finally, where Dispose is called in the finally block. It's true you can't always do much. But without catching the Exception what are you going to log? Exception.message can often be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

(2) can be further composed, whilst (1) just runs. But neither are exactly "functional" as `Action` is not a function (compare with `Func<A, R>`).

So with (2) you could do:

```
Fault(someAction, Fault(firstTryFaultHandler, lastDitchFaultHandler))();
```

...and get expected behavior. That doesn't work with (1)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "can be further composed"?

Comment: A fault of a fault? Are we crossing the line between practice and theory here? :) Also I am wondering if one is more efficient than the other.

Comment: I could have written a more complicated (though perhaps more realistic) example using an entirely separate function (e.g., `IfThen`), but it seemed clearer to use the example in your question. Efficiency should be similar as in this case the expression is interpreted at compile time.

Comment: @Carlo: get the variable from memory.  If an exception occurs, find it on the local file system.  If an exception occurs, notify the user.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, approach 2 can be confusing. A caller might use "Fault(a, b);" expecting a and possibly b to be called. Instead, a lambda is created, returned and discarded. In other words nothing is done.

Regarding efficiency, approach 2 is a bit wasteful if most of your calls are of the form "Fault(a,b)();", i.e. you invoke the lambda immediately. In this situation, you don't need a lambda.

For these reasons, I would prefer approach 1. If you need to defer execution, you can introduce a lambda explicitly "() => Fault(a, b)".